# equal column spacing in longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable, multicolumn

Does anyone know how to get equal spacing between columns in longtable? My code is attached below. 
Thanks.
Franz

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} %\usepackage{float} \usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{setspace} \usepackage{color} \usepackage{geometry}  
\geometry{a4paper,left=25.4mm,right=25.4mm,top=25.4mm,bottom=25.4mm} 
\usepackage{epsfig} \usepackage{epstopdf} \epstopdfsetup{update} 
\usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{dcolumn} \usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{caption} \usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage{longtable}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.7}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{longtable}{l*{7}{c}}
\caption{Unconditional Quantile Wage Regressions: Non-performance paid, 2003-2004 \label{tab rifquantnw0304}}\\
    \hline\hline\endfirsthead\hline\endhead\hline\endfoot\endlastfoot
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF10}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF25}&\multicolumn{1}{r}{RIF50}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF75}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF90}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{RIF95}\\
        \hline
    Age                 &      0.0930\sym{**} &      0.0847\sym{***}&       0.127\sym{***}&       0.105\sym{***}      &      0.0275         &      -0.150\sym{***}&      -0.189\sym{***} \\
                        &      (3.14)         &      (4.42)         &      (7.52)         &      (7.04)               &      (1.78)       &     (-6.13)         &     (-5.77)         \\
    Age squared/1000    &      -1.283\sym{***}&      -1.100\sym{***}&      -1.326\sym{***}&      -1.081\sym{***}     &      -0.217         &       1.804\sym{***}&       2.217\sym{***} \\
                        &     (-3.64)         &     (-5.04)         &     (-7.78)         &     (-7.31)         &     (-1.39)       &      (6.95)         &      (6.07)         \\
    Female              &      -0.109\sym{**} &      -0.253\sym{***}&      -0.401\sym{***}&      -0.364\sym{***}     &           -0.227\sym{***}&      -0.186\sym{***}&      -0.129\sym{***} \\
                        &     (-2.66)         &     (-7.56)         &    (-13.53)         &    (-15.18)         &     (-9.87)       &     (-6.54)         &     (-3.98)         \\
    Married             &      0.0324         &     -0.0387         &    -0.00840         &      0.0631\sym{*}       &       0.147\sym{***}&       0.122\sym{***}&       0.118\sym{***}\\
                        &      (0.75)         &     (-1.41)         &     (-0.33)         &      (2.51)         &      (5.68)       &      (4.10)         &      (4.35)         \\
    Number of kids      &     -0.0501         &     -0.0390         &    -0.00465         &     0.00457         &     -0.0178       &    -0.00818         &      0.0195         \\
                        &     (-1.14)         &     (-1.31)         &     (-0.19)         &      (0.21)         &     (-0.75)       &     (-0.22)         &      (0.44)         \\
    Elementary school   &     -0.0545         &      -0.220\sym{**} &      -0.199\sym{***}&      -0.103\sym{**}      &     0.00754         &      0.0672\sym{*}  &       0.122\sym{**} \\
                        &     (-0.52)         &     (-3.06)         &     (-4.76)         &     (-3.19)         &      (0.23)       &      (2.01)         &      (2.93)         \\

    \hline
    Observations        &        5882         &        5882         &        5882         &        5882         &        5882         &        5882         &        5882         \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{longtable}
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Christian: Many thanks for editing my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I realize your question appears to be about getting equal widths *between* the columns of a `longtable`. However, since the intercolumn whitespace is given by `2\tabcolsep`, the intercolumn widths are already equal. I therefore interpret your question as being about getting the *column widths* to be equal.)

In the present case, since you're already loading the `dcolumn` package, you may achieve your objective by (i) defining a new column type named `d` that does decimal alignment of the numbers and (ii) replacing the `c` specification with `d{3.6}`. Doing so will ensure that the `d`-type columns all have the same width; therefore, the horizontal distances from decimal point to decimal point are constant across adjacent columns.

Separately, since you're loading the `booktabs` package, you may also want to replace the various `\hline` instructions with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc.

It turns out not to be necessary to go to `\scriptsize`, i.e., a ca. 30% linear reduction in font size, in order to get the table to fit. Executing `\footnotesize`(which brings about a ca. 20% font size reduction) suffices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
%% I've commented out the packages that aren't needed for this MWE
%\usepackage{import} 
%\usepackage{amsmath} 
%\usepackage{amsfonts} 
%\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{float} 
%\usepackage{lscape} 
%\usepackage{setspace} 
%\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
%\usepackage{epsfig} 
%\usepackage{epstopdf} 
%\epstopdfsetup{update} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
%\usepackage{natbib} 
%\usepackage{caption} 
%\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
%%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.7}
\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{7}{d{3.6}} @{}} % replace "c" with "d{3.6}"
\caption{Unconditional Quantile Wage Regressions: Non-performance paid, 2003--2004} 
\label{tab rifquantnw0304}\\
\toprule\endfirsthead
\midrule\endhead
\midrule\endfoot
\bottomrule\endlastfoot
&\mc{RIF5}& \mc{RIF10}& \mc{RIF25}& \mc{RIF50}& \mc{RIF75}& \mc{RIF90}& \mc{RIF95}\\
\midrule
Age                 &      0.0930\sym{**} &      0.0847\sym{***}&       0.127\sym{***}&       0.105\sym{***}      &      0.0275         &      -0.150\sym{***}&      -0.189\sym{***} \\
                    &      (3.14)         &      (4.42)         &      (7.52)         &      (7.04)               &      (1.78)       &     (-6.13)         &     (-5.77)         \\
Age squared/1000    &      -1.283\sym{***}&      -1.100\sym{***}&      -1.326\sym{***}&      -1.081\sym{***}     &      -0.217         &       1.804\sym{***}&       2.217\sym{***} \\
                    &     (-3.64)         &     (-5.04)         &     (-7.78)         &     (-7.31)         &     (-1.39)       &      (6.95)         &      (6.07)         \\
Female              &      -0.109\sym{**} &      -0.253\sym{***}&      -0.401\sym{***}&      -0.364\sym{***}     &           -0.227\sym{***}&      -0.186\sym{***}&      -0.129\sym{***} \\
                    &     (-2.66)         &     (-7.56)         &    (-13.53)         &    (-15.18)         &     (-9.87)       &     (-6.54)         &     (-3.98)         \\
Married             &      0.0324         &     -0.0387         &    -0.00840         &      0.0631\sym{*}       &       0.147\sym{***}&       0.122\sym{***}&       0.118\sym{***}\\
                    &      (0.75)         &     (-1.41)         &     (-0.33)         &      (2.51)         &      (5.68)       &      (4.10)         &      (4.35)         \\
Number of kids      &     -0.0501         &     -0.0390         &    -0.00465         &     0.00457         &     -0.0178       &    -0.00818         &      0.0195         \\
                    &     (-1.14)         &     (-1.31)         &     (-0.19)         &      (0.21)         &     (-0.75)       &     (-0.22)         &      (0.44)         \\
Elementary school   &     -0.0545         &      -0.220\sym{**} &      -0.199\sym{***}&      -0.103\sym{**}      &     0.00754         &      0.0672\sym{*}  &       0.122\sym{**} \\
                    &     (-0.52)         &     (-3.06)         &     (-4.76)         &     (-3.19)         &      (0.23)       &      (2.01)         &      (2.93)         \\

\midrule
Observations        & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         & \mc{5882}         \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup % end of scope of \footnotesize directive
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Your suggestion works perfect for me. Is there a way I can also include a note to this table? I have tried this one just before \end{longtable} but it does not work for me: \multicolumn{8}{l}{\tiny \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\

Comment: @Franz - You can make such a note a part of `\endlastfoot`, right? E.g., `\midrule \multicolumn{8}{l}}\textit{t}-statistics in parentheses}\\ \endlastfoot`.